# I can't display heading, company, location, date. I tried end='', but it's not working

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I am working on a web-scraping project (monster.com). Everything is working, but I wanted to display the the relevant info on the same line (heading, company, location, date), but I can't I tried end='', but it doesn't work

```
from locators.jobs_locators import JobsLocators

class JobsParser:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.heading}, at {self.company}, located in {self.location}, posted {self.date}"

    @property
    def heading(self):
        return self.parent.select_one(JobsLocators.HEADING).string

    @property
    def company(self):
        try:
            return self.parent.select_one(JobsLocators.COMPANY).string
        except:
            return self.parent.select_one(JobsLocators.COMPANY1).string

    @property
    def location(self):
        try:
            return self.parent.select_one(JobsLocators.LOCATION).string
        except:
            return self.parent.select_one(JobsLocators.COMPANY1).string

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self.parent.select_one(JobsLocators.DATE).string
```

Comment: Please place code inline in your OP, not as a link to an image

Comment: Please also provide a minimally reproducible example

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't have any print statement. Please paste the problematic code.